# Use same wordpress category base and tags as the prefix as the post permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks

I want to use wordpress permalink structure as
/blog/category/post-name

And I also want the archive pages to be like
/blog/category

In order to keep permalink structure

When I apply on the structure
/blog/%category%/%post-name%
and in the base
/blog/. or just /blog
it turns or the blog page 2 or the archives page 2 to error page.

Anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: This won't work because WordPress will not be able to tell if a URL is intended to be for a category or a post. They need to be distinguished somehow.

Comment: It works when is a custom post type, using rewrite. But it doesn't for normal posts